# Comparing firestore timestamps in .where() not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

This is my code:

```js
...

const submitted_at = threads[0].data.submitted_at.toDate();
const ref = firestore()
        .collection('Discover')
        .where('submitted_at', '>', `${submitted_at}`)
// Also tried comparing using new Date(submitted_at) but it still did not work
        .orderBy('submitted_at', 'desc')
        .limit(10);
...
```

`QuerySnapshot` is always empty

This is a pull to refresh query whose purpose is to fetch documents that were submitted after the first document that was retrieved.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, it looks like you are turning a Date into a string:

```
.where('submitted_at', '>', `${submitted_at}`)
```

That's not going to work.  If you want to pass a Date to a query to compare to a timestamp field, don't convert it to anything else.  It must be a Date type:

```
.where('submitted_at', '>', submitted_at)
```